# Can scan with simple scanner in Epson Stylus 525WD

Tags: scanner

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and I need my epson to scan something. I can't, however, find a way to make it work. Using the "simple scan" app, it says "cannot connect to device", as if no scan was connected to it.

The model of the printer is the following:

Epson Stylus 525WD

Comment: You have installed `iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb` or `iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb` as well as `iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb`?

Comment: Sorry I confused Simple Scan and Image Scan (Epson). You can get the packages there: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX If Simple Scan can't find the scanner afterwards install XSane.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the drivers from the [Epson website](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX).

Install either `iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb` or `iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb` depending on the architecture you are using as well as `iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb`.

If "Simple Scan" still can't find the scanner install [XSane](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xsane/).